# what is reason unable to boot- in my oracle virtual box vm?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, virtualbox

i have oracle vm virtualbox .When i  try to configure linux in virtual box i am getting error like below

```
" loading vmlinuz..............
loading initrd.img.............ready.
this kernel required an X86-64 cpu , but only detected an i686CPU.
unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your cpu ."
```

Answer (score 2):

`i686` is a 32-bit CPU arch, and you are trying to load a 64-bit kernel. You need to either change the VM CPU arch, or load a different kernel, so they match.